# Read first line of file when opening to rename buffer

Tags: hooks

I want to add a hook that reads the first line of the file/buffer when it opens. 
I want to do this so that I can rename the buffer that opens notes from simplenote.

But, how do I read the first line?

I guess I was kind of vague in my question. But exactly what I wanted to do was to read the first line when opening notes via simplenote.el since the buffer gets named to a hash of 76 char that does not tell anything about the contents.

This kind of failed since opening a simplenote file it defaults to text mode so no hook possible there. But it could be useful for org-mode notes in simplenote.

Using something like this:

```
  (defun read-first-line ()
    (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (setq b (point))
    (setq e (- (search-forward "-*-" (line-end-position)) 4))
    (buffer-substring-no-properties b e)))


;(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
      ;(lambda () (rename-buffer (read-first-line))))

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
     (lambda () ((let (str (read-first-line))
              (if (not (string= "" str))
                  (rename-buffer str))))))
```

I cannot get the conditional lambda to work.
And what is the difference with let and setq inside a function?

Edit:
Fixed the org-mode-hook:

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
        (let ((str (read-first-line)))
          (if (not (string= "" str))
          (rename-buffer str)))))
```

Comment: What do you mean "read"? Does the following do what you want? (defun read-first-line ()
  (save-excursion)
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (let ((b (point))
 (e (progn (end-of-line) (point))))
    (buffer-substring-no-properties b e)))

Comment: Yes that was what I meant. Fetch the content of the first line.

Comment: `(defun read-first-line ()
  (save-excursion
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (let
      ((b (point))
       (e (progn (end-of-line) (point))))
    (buffer-substring-no-properties b e))))`

Moved the parenthesis of save-excursion if some one else tries this code.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Have a look at the [manual note on hooks](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Hooks.html).

Comment: @Rickard Do you want to rename the buffer name (and not the file name) each time you open a buffer, based on the first line in the buffer? If so please rephrase the question so that it includes the "renaming buffer" portion too.

Comment: The difference between `setq` and `let` is that `setq` changes the value of a variable globally, whereas `let` only changes it temporarily inside the function. (However, if you apply `let` to a global variable, the changed value is seen by all functions you call from your function.)

Comment: Why do you say "*text mode so no hook possible there*". There is `text-mode-hook`. The question could maybe be clearer?

Comment: @Drew the reason I wanted to rename the buffer in the first place was using a simplenote plugin that named the buffer to some long non-descripting hash.
And what I meant with the "text mode so no hook possible" was that when the document was opened it was no way to determine if the document was a regular text file or some special file because the current emacs mode was just text mode.

Maybe a regex for the hash could have been used.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: Whoever edited my answer, way to go asshole. Now it's fucking meaningless. Next time just delete the reply. That way the asker won't be confused by a non-working answer.

I don't understand how or why you want to rename
the buffer, or if it can be done programatically.
You'll have to suppy more details about your
intended applications and expected results.
Therefore this code is designed to demonstrate
one approach which will require tailoring to
fit your needs.

This function must accept a single argument!
The argument is the number of characters inserted.
This function must return the number of characters
remaining in the buffer after processing. We don't
change the buffer contents after insertion, so the
original argument will be passed back unchanged.

This function must not return a string or any value
other than the number of characters remaining!
The best we can do is print the line, or
insert it in another buffer, or perform other side
effects. I have chosen to print the line to
demonstrate that this works.

When this function is called, `point` will initially
be set to `(point-min)`. That is why the function
operates on the "current line".

```
(defun my-print-this-line (n)
  "Print current line to *Messages*."
  (message "%s"
       (buffer-substring-no-properties (line-beginning-position)
                       (line-end-position)))
  n)
;; => my-print-this-line
(setq after-insert-file-functions '(my-print-this-line))
:: => (my-print-this-line)
```

- https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Format-Conversion-Piecemeal.html#Format-Conversion-Piecemeal